# Glossary entries for multiple glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I'm currently writing my thesis and would like to present section-wise glossaries. I've created multiple new glossaries which show all the acronyms i want them to.

One problem remains, there are some definitions which should show up in multiple glossaries, is there any way to achieve this?

At the moment entries show only up once.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage[section=subsection]{glossaries}


\newglossary{No1}{1i}{1o}   {Glossary 1}
\newglossary{No2}{2i}{2o}{Glossary 2}

\newglossaryentry{1}{type=No1,name=Entry1,description=Desc1}
\newglossaryentry{2}{type=No2,name=Entry2,description=Desc2}
\newglossaryentry{3}{type=No2,type=No1,name=Entry3,description=Desc3}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\printglossary[type=No1]
\gls{1},\gls{3}
\section{Section 2}
\printglossary[type=No2]
\gls{2},\gls{3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the entry after printing the first glossary:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[section=subsection]{glossaries}


\newglossary{No1}{1i}{1o}   {Glossary 1}
\newglossary{No2}{2i}{2o}{Glossary 2}

\newglossaryentry{1}{type=No1,name=Entry1,description=Desc1}
\newglossaryentry{2}{type=No2,name=Entry2,description=Desc2}
\newglossaryentry{3}{type=No1,name=Entry3,description=Desc3}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\printglossary[type=No1]
\gls{1},\gls{3}
\section{Section 2}
\glsmoveentry{3}{No2}
\printglossary[type=No2]
\gls{2},\gls{3}
\end{document}
```

[image: duplicate entry]

Note that I'm not sure if this will have untoward side-effects. ***Caveat emptor...***